# Need to confirm bug in Dataset options before I submit report to wolfram

Tags: dataset, options, associations, style, object-oriented

I need to know if I need to submit a bug report. I finally got my `HeaderSize` the way I want it but I had fudge it. It gives the correct widths but does this look right to you?

```
HeaderSize -> {4, {12, 12, 12, 6, 6}},(* gives 4,12,12,12,6,6 *)
```

Shouldn't this work instead (but gives wrong widths)?

```
HeaderSize -> {4, {12}, 6, 6},(* gives 4,12,4,4,4,4 *)
```

Or this (also gives wrong widths)?

```
HeaderSize -> {4, 12, 12, 12, 6, 6},(* gives 4,12,12,12,12,12 *)
```

The full *"working"* code is below...

```
Dataset[
 <|
  "aaa" -> <|"one" -> 11, "two" -> 12, "three" -> 13, "four" -> 14, 
    "five" -> 15|>,
  "bbb" -> <|"one" -> 21, "two" -> 22, "three" -> 23, "four" -> 24, 
    "five" -> 25|>,
  "ccc" -> <|"one" -> 31, "two" -> 32, "three" -> 33, "four" -> 34, 
    "five" -> 35|>,
  "dddd" -> <|"one" -> 41, "two" -> 42, "three" -> 43, "four" -> 44, 
    "five" -> 45|>,
  "eeee" -> <|"one" -> 51, "two" -> 52, "three" -> 53, "four" -> 54, 
    "five" -> 55|>,
  "ffff" -> <|"one" -> 61, "two" -> 62, "three" -> 63, "four" -> 64, 
    "five" -> 65|>
  |>,
 HeaderSize -> {4, {12, 12, 12, 6, 6}},
 HeaderStyle -> Directive[10, White],
 HeaderAlignment -> {Center, Bottom},
 HeaderBackground -> GrayLevel[.25],
 ItemSize -> {Automatic, 1},
 ItemStyle -> Directive[10, White, FontFamily -> "Courier New"],
 Alignment -> {Center, Bottom},
 Background -> Black
 ]
```

Comment: I can verify that either the help is in correct or it is a bugg. I would report it to wolfram.

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks, will do